# Use skrollr to change color nav links anchor

Tags: html, css

I would like to change the color of my nav links if the anchor reach my target. It works fine if I use the data attributes on my `<a>`, but not if I would like to use it on my `<nav>` for all links.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6FMsA/1

This is what I've tried:

```
       data-anchor-target="#change" 
       data-0="color: rgba(0,0,0,1);" 
       data-top="color: rgba(255,255,255,1);"
       data-top-bottom="color: rgba(0,0,0,1);"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your JavaScript has invalid syntax.

Apart from that, it's not related to skrollr. You defined a color for the links in your stylesheet and there's no reason they should inherit the color of the nav element. If you want this, use `color:inherit`.

http://jsfiddle.net/6FMsA/2/

Comment: Maybe you could help me? Would it possible to use skrollr data anchors more then one time? For example always on dark background? http://jsfiddle.net/6FMsA/3/

Comment: @l00per Unfortunately no, that's not possible. Also having the same ID twice is invalid. Your only option is not use another element around the nav.